# Saving e-mail attachments using Excel values as input for file name

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, email-attachments

I'm a bit new to coding, but here goes :)

I receive e-mail attachments that I need to save with a particular name format using information found in an Excel worksheet.

- The row containing the information I need can be identified by the subject line of the e-mail.

I'd like to write some code to do the following for selected e-mails in Outlook:

1. Find the row containing the information needed using the subject line of the e-mail
2. Return values from several fields in that row
3. Use those values and the subject line to create a file name
4. Save the file in a specified directory

I've managed to find and rewrite some copied code to save attachments using the subject line as file name only. I'm struggling with getting the information from the Excel sheet to append that to the file name.

Here's my code so far:

```
Sub SaveAttachments()

Dim objOL As Outlook.Application
Dim objMsg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
Dim i As Long
Dim lngCount As Long
Dim strFile As String
Dim strFolderpath As String
Dim strFileName As String
Dim objSubject As String
Dim strDeletedFiles As String 


strFolderpath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders(16)
On Error Resume Next

' Instantiate an Outlook Application object.
Set objOL = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

' Get the collection of selected objects.
Set objSelection = objOL.ActiveExplorer.Selection

' Set the Attachment folder.
strFolderpath = "C:\Users\User\Documents\"

' Check each selected item for attachments.
For Each objMsg In objSelection

'Set FileName to Subject
objSubject = objMsg.Subject

Set objAttachments = objMsg.Attachments

lngCount = objAttachments.Count
If lngCount > 0 Then
' Use a count down loop for removing items
' from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets
' confused and only every other item is removed.
For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

' Get the file name.
strFileName = objSubject & ".pdf"

' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
strFile = strFolderpath & strFileName
Debug.Print strFile
' Save the attachment as a file.
objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
Next i
End If
Next

ExitSub:
Set objAttachments = Nothing
Set objMsg = Nothing
Set objSelection = Nothing
Set objOL = Nothing
End Sub
```

I'm guessing I need to write a function to return the values from the Excel sheet, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: It might be easier (from a syntax perspective) to actually do this in Excel, not Outlook. In either case you need to grab the instance of the other application if it's running - or create an instance of the application if not - to access it's properties and methods.

Comment: @MacroMan based on the `CreateObject` function call, it looks like OP is doing this *from* Excel, binding *to* the Outlook application :)

Comment: @DavidZemens (d'oh) - Sometimes I amaze myself at how much I _don't_ read in these posts.... :$

Answer (score 0):

To keep your code as un-cluttered as possible, let's make a function to get the information from Excel worksheet:

1. Find the row containing the information needed using the subject
   line of the e-mail
2. Return values from several fields in that row
3. Use those values and the subject line to create a file name
4. Save the file in a specified directory

Assuming the subject lines < 255 characters, and are unique (no duplicates), something like this:

```
Function GetInfoFromWorksheet(ws as Worksheet, mail as Outlook.MailItem)
'  Finds a subject in the worksheet and returns the concatenated
'   values from several cells in that row
'  worksheet:  the sheet which contains the outlook info/details
'  mail:       the outlook mailitem being processed


    Dim row as Long
    Dim rng as Range
    Dim combinedValues as String
    Dim subject as String
    Dim ret As String

    subject = mail.Subject
    '#1 Find the subject in Column A, modify if needed
    Set rng = Application.Match(subject, ws.Range("A:A"), False)
    If not rng Is Nothing Then
        row = rng.Row
    Else
        ret = ""
        GoTo EarlyExit
    End If

    '#2, #3 Once we know the row, then you can pull out additional info
    '   from this row and combine them like so.
    '   Example combines column B and Column F, modify as needed:
     ret = ws.Cells(row, 2) & ws.Cells(row, 6) 'Etc


EarlyExit:
    SaveAttachments = ret
End Function
```

From your procedure, call it like so:

```
For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
    ' Get the file name.
     strFileName = GetInfoFromWorksheet(ActiveSheet, objMsg)
     If strFileName = "" Then 
         ' the function returns an empty string, then the subject wasn't found in Excel sheet
          MsgBox objMsg & " not found in Excel sheet!", vbInformation


     Else:
         'the details were found in Excel, so save the file:
          strFileName = strFileName & ".pdf"
         ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
         strFile = strFolderpath & strFileName
         Debug.Print strFile
         ' Save the attachment as a file.
         objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
     End If
Next
```

**Note:** This may not work for an item with multiple attachments, as the row matching the subject line will be the same for each attachment, and so it will return the same information, you'll end up with the same filename for each attachment.  You could easily modify the function, or your calling procedure to append the `i` value to the filename that way ensuring unique names for each attachment.  Like:

```
     'the details were found in Excel, so save the file:
      strFileName = strFileName & Cstr(i) & ".pdf"
```

**Another note:** Get rid of `On Error Resume Next` and handle errors properly...

Comment: Hi David,

Thanks for the reply!

This might be a newbie question, but where and how do I define which workbook and worksheet to return the data from?

Preferably, I'd like to set a filepath rather than having to keep the source file open.

Comment: Instead of sending `ActiveSheet` to the function, you can send it another sheet, i.e.t, `Workbooks("Myfile.xlsx").Sheets("Some Worksheet")`. This requires the workbook to be already open, though.  The function could be modified to take a *path* and *worksheet name*. Why don't you give it a try?  I'm not writing the code for you, but I can help if you get stuck.

Comment: Hi David, thanks again for the help! After a bit of trial and error I was able to get it working. Your comment about proper error handling helped a lot, didn't realise I had that piece of code in there. After I was able set the correct workbook and worksheet, `Match` kept giving me errors in the function, but I fixed that by using `Find` instead.

Comment: Cheers..consider up voting or accepting the answer if it's helped you, that's the preferred way of showing gratitude around here :)